# Help required with a multiple table join not returning null / blank

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (s_place, s_place_bing, s_place_yahoo) which have the same schema, and contain similar results from three different sources. What I would like is a query that returns all results from the three tables which match a given s_u_id, s_q_id and date.

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| s_u_id          | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| s_q_id          | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| place           | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fullurl         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| above_today     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| above_yesterday | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| below_today     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| below_yesterday | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| yesterday       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

It's quite likely that there will be more results in one table than there are in another for the same s_u_id, s_q_id and date. In this case, it should return null or blank rows for the table(s) which have no data.

I have got this far using the query below, however it isn't returning null / blanks.

```
SELECT s_place.s_u_id, s_place.s_q_id, `s_place`.place as place, `s_place`.fullurl as fullurl, `s_place`.date as date, s_place_bing.place as b_place,`s_place_bing`.fullurl as b_fullurl, s_place_bing.date as b_date, s_place_yahoo.place as y_place, `s_place_yahoo`.fullurl as y_fullurl, s_place_yahoo.date as y_date
from s_place
left join s_place_bing on s_place_bing.s_q_id = s_place.s_q_id and s_place_bing.date = s_place.date
left join s_place_yahoo on s_place_yahoo.s_q_id = s_place.s_q_id and s_place_yahoo.date = s_place.date
where s_place.s_u_id = 1 and s_place.s_q_id = 64
order by s_place.date desc

+--------+--------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+
| s_u_id | s_q_id | place | fullurl              | date       | b_place | b_fullurl                | b_date     | y_place | y_fullurl         | y_date     |
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+
|      1 |     64 |    39 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292112000 |      30 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1292112000 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292112000 |
|      1 |     64 |    39 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292112000 |      65 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1292112000 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292112000 |
|      1 |     64 |    36 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292025600 |      30 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1292025600 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292025600 |
|      1 |     64 |    36 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292025600 |      64 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1292025600 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292025600 |
|      1 |     64 |    40 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291939200 |      66 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1291939200 |    9999 |                   | 1291939200 |
|      1 |     64 |    40 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291939200 |      29 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1291939200 |    9999 |                   | 1291939200 |
|      1 |     64 |    38 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291852800 |      29 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1291852800 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1291852800 |
|      1 |     64 |    38 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291852800 |      68 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1291852800 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1291852800 |
```

This is how it *should* return the data.

```
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+
| s_u_id | s_q_id | place | fullurl              | date       | b_place | b_fullurl                | b_date     | y_place | y_fullurl         | y_date     |
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------------+
|      1 |      4 |    39 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292112000 |      30 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1292112000 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292112000 |
|      1 |     64 |       |                      |            |      65 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1292112000 |         |                   |            |
|      1 |     64 |    36 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1292025600 |      30 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1292025600 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1292025600 |
|      1 |     64 |       |                      |            |      64 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1292025600 |         |                   |            |
|      1 |     64 |    40 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291939200 |      66 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1291939200 |    9999 |                   | 1291939200 |
|      1 |     64 |       |                      |            |      29 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1291939200 |         |                   |            |
|      1 |     64 |    38 |        rrr.co.uk     | 1291852800 |      29 |        rrr.co.uk         | 1291852800 |       6 |        rrr.co.uk  | 1291852800 |
|      1 |     64 |       |                      |            |      68 |        rrr.co.uk search/ | 1291852800 |         |                   |            |
```

Hope someone can help. Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your *desired* result set, the only fully populated column(s) are from your `s_place_bing` table.  So, from the result set you show, it looks like you should be `LEFT JOIN`ing your `s_place` and `s_place_yahoo` tables to your `s_place_bing` table.

Having said that, your current query is sorting on `s_place.date desc`, but your desired result set has empties/nulls in that field.

Does this give you the result you want?

```
SELECT 
    b.s_u_id, b.s_q_id, 
    p.place AS p_place, p.fullurl AS p_fullurl, p.date AS p_date,
    b.place AS b_place, b.fullurl AS b_fullurl, b.date AS b_date, 
    y.place AS y_place, y.fullurl AS y_fullurl, y.date AS y_date
FROM s_place_bing b 
LEFT JOIN s_place p ON b.s_q_id = p.s_q_id AND b.date = p.date
LEFT JOIN s_place_yahoo y ON b.s_q_id = y.s_q_id AND b.date = y.date
WHERE b.s_u_id = 1 and b.s_q_id = 64
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```